# Detect if the MIDlet is installing or running for the first time

Tags: java-me, installation, initialization, midlet

I'm using J2ME SDK 3.0 and J2ME Polish and i would like to know if there's any event that is called when the user installs the application or when the MIDlet is running for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific "first run" event.  However, when the MIDlet starts, the system will invoke [`MIDlet.startApp()`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#startApp%28%29).  You can implement your own "first run" detection by creating a RecordStore and saving some information in it.  If the RecordStore does not exist, then it's first run.  If it does, then you have run the MIDlet before.